# Can I or can't I develop on a jailbreak iphone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

Does any one have a defenative answer?

I am reading so many answers that tell you both thing, one tells you that it is not a problem atall and the other one is very defente NO...Is there any developer over here that has a jailbreaked iphone that is using it to test the application in development?

From what i heard from friends, Not over the web, Apple don't allow that and is checking for that, but over the web i've read that it is not a problem....

I will eventualy remove the stupid (in my eyes, sorry everyone) jailbreak that was installed on my lovely iphone, but i want to know if to do it now or can i wait with that because i want the person that installed it to remove it and give me the iphone i asked for....never mind, if i can wait, I preffer to do it this way (might take weeks of month as we do not leave in the same place) but if i have to, i will do it by myself and that's all..

10x.

Comment: Can you please tell me why did you gave me -1? not only that i want to work with the iphone, but stupid people that sell them and fix them all over the world thing they can do what ever they want with it, now i am asking a real question and you not only answering me but give me -1? 10x.... :-(

Comment: You might get fewer downvotes if you remove the personal ranting from the last paragraph.  Just ask your question in a polite, non-confrontational way.

Comment: O, Ok Kristopher, thank you, Just blew so steem of, i guess, mabye it came out too strong, But i am still made about it.... But if you don't mind (And if you look at my other posts, this is not the way i usually talk) I will leave it as it is this time....maybe people (might be smarter them me people) will not do my mistakes after reading this. 10x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

No, you shouldn't, not if you want to submit to the App Store, as there may be differences in app behaviour between a jailbroken and stock iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

You can develop apps using a jailbroken phone, and Apple will have no idea that you are doing so.

However, if you don't test with a non-jailbroken device, you may miss some problems.  So the smart thing to do is to test on non-jailbroken devices before submission to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a lot of iOS devices already and also tested it on my apps on development.

Actually, the truth is there are many people had their iPhone's jailbroken.
So it is your **advantage as a developer** to see how your app works on a jailbroken one when you run and debug it on your iphone.

Some of the features supposedly working for the non-jailbroken iphone are not working on jailbroken one. e.g. **before, the Push Notifications on 3.1.3 are not working on jailbroken phones**.

take a look at Paypal's app, they even recognize that problem that they have to include it on a notice on their Push Notification Feature.

Comment: Thank you all so much.... It is just for a while untill I do it, I just don't want to do it by my self if i can avoid it.... So just needed to know for now so I will know i am not violating any Apple law and get in trouble, like they will close my developer account, for a stupid thing like this. Don't you hate people for the stupid things they do? P.S. Can any one tell me why i was deducted the point for this? Not that it matter, but i wan't to know...It was wierd for me...10x again, very much...

Comment: And johnoodles, Sorry man, I don't see it your way, i don't think it is an advantage to brake the law....or to support law brakers for that matter...I know i might be kind of a nurd in this matter and sound like a prud, but it is just the same as i would not build the perfect streat race care just becouse many people has it so i can test it can make theirs better... But i do thank you very much for the answer.... :-)

Comment: Jailbreaking an iPhone is not necessarily "breaking the law". Apple doesn't like it, but that doesn't make it illegal.

Comment: Well, maybe i'm wrong about it, It won't me my first, nor last... It is just the way i see things :-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't as the main device. It can give you a lot of headache.

Also keep in mind:

- Apple doesn't like it. If they figure it out, well, it's not an advantage. Maybe they can even remove from the App Development Program, although I'm not sure about that.
- In-app purchase does not work well or at all. That's a major downside
- There is no point supporting JB devices, because they can even differ from each other significantly
- More apps are running on a JB phone, so you can run into more memory and incompatibility issues.